# SQL Query to get the List of all database and server name from Oracle Enterprise Manager (OEM)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

When multiple instances are configured with OEM, And you have such a requirement to implement or to get the list of the instances from the SQL command-line interface or GUI.

Answer (score 1):

This query will help you to get the list of Instances name along with Other information, you can check out `SYSMAN.MGMT$TARGET` view for more details.

```
set lines 200
col DATABASE_NAME for a40
col DATABASE_VERSION for a20
col SERVER for a40
col OS for a20
col OS_VERSION for a60
select db.TARGET_NAME DATABASE_NAME, db.TYPE_QUALIFIER1 DATABASE_VERSION, os.TARGET_NAME SERVER, os.TYPE_QUALIFIER1 OS, os.TYPE_QUALIFIER2 OS_VERSION
from SYSMAN.MGMT$TARGET db, SYSMAN.MGMT$TARGET os 
where db.HOST_NAME = os.TARGET_NAME 
and db.target_type='oracle_database'
and os.target_type='host'
order by 1;
```